# (node:11168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: List validation failed

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am Working on a todo list it's a pet project, I am getting an error :
`(node:11168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: List validation failed: items.3._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "sas" at path "_id"`

full error:

```
(node:11168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: List validation failed: items.3._id: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "sas" at path "_id"
    at model.Document.invalidate (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:2688:32)
    at EmbeddedDocument.invalidate (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:292:29)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1301:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument.$set (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:1010:16)
    at EmbeddedDocument.Document (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\document.js:150:12)
    at EmbeddedDocument [as constructor] (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\embedded.js:42:12)
    at new EmbeddedDocument (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\schema\documentarray.js:115:17)
    at CoreDocumentArray._cast (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\documentarray.js:109:12)
    at CoreDocumentArray._mapCast (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\core_array.js:272:17)
    at Arguments.map (<anonymous>)
    at CoreDocumentArray.push (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\core_array.js:670:21)
    at CoreDocumentArray.push (C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\types\documentarray.js:210:28)
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\app.js:76:35
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\model.js:4846:16
    at C:\Users\Lenovo\Documents\todolist-v2-starting-files\node_modules\mongoose\lib\helpers\promiseOrCallback.js:24:16
(node:11168) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11168) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Code:

```
app.post("/", function(req, res){
  const itemName = req.body.newItem;
  const listTitle = req.body.listTitle;

  if(listTitle === "Today"){
    const item = new Item ({
      name: itemName
    });

    item.save();
    res.redirect("/");
  }else{
      List.findOne({name: listTitle}, function(err, foundCustomList){
        
          if(err){
            console.log(err);
          }if(!err){
            foundCustomList.items.push(itemName);
            foundCustomList.save();
            res.render("list", {listTitle: foundCustomList.name, newListItems: foundCustomList.items});
          }
      })
  }
});
```

as far As am aware. I am getting this error on pushing >> `foundCustomList.items.push(itemName);`

Here's the schema definition........................

```
const listSchema = {
  name: String,
  items: [itemsSchema]
};

const List = mongoose.model("List", listSchema);
```

It's using the itemsSchema.........

```
const itemsSchema = {
  name: String
};

const Item = mongoose.model("Item", itemsSchema);
```

Comment: Include the schema definition please.

Comment: You can push your data using mongodb syntax, `List.findOneAndUpdate({name:listTitle}, {$push:{yourItemArrayNameHere:itemName}}).then(data=>{}).catch(err=>{})` , if you use mongoose, you need to use mongoose Schema first before making a query